# Using DocuSign with Postman

Tags: docusignapi, postman

I'm new to DocuSign and I want to use postman (https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) to make basic DocuSign requests.

For example:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Send an Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7CSend%2520an%2520Envelope%2520or%2520Create%2520a%2520Draft%2520Envelope%7C_____0

I'm getting stuck.  I already have an Integrator Key.

How can I set up Postman to make basic DocuSign calls?

Comment: [Here's](https://blog.grigsbyconsultingllc.com/postman-rest-client-a-google-chrome-app/) a blog post that should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official DocuSign blog on how to connect postman to DocuSign.  See the link here:  https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman/

This link walks through the process of importing the DocuSign Rest API into postman, complete with many recipes.

The DocuSign API Explorer is nice, but postman generates code for many languages and does a bit more than just using the API Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use DocuSign's **API Explorer** tool?  It is specifically designed for what you are trying to do - you can make REST API calls without writing any code, and see the outgoing request and the incoming response for each call.

To use the tool simply input your sandbox credentials (username, pwd, integrator key), select the method you want to call, and hit the *Try It* button:

[DocuSign API Explorer](http://iodocs.docusign.com/)